# clarification in the connection string for accessing database over lan

Tags: ms-access, c#-4.0

Can anyone please tell that the user id and password specified in the following connection string refers to the credentials for server access or for accessing the ms-access database file.

```
  Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=\\serverName\shareName\folder\myDatabase.mdb;User Id=admin;Password=;
```

I have an access database that is stored on a server that requires credentials for accessing it but my database file does not have any credentials.

I am facing problem in accessing the database. Please help

EDIT: Thanks for clarification.

Can someone tell me the way to provide server access credentials through coding in C#.
I am using OLADB connection string.

Comment: All you have done is completely changed the question making the answers invalid, not asked a new question.

Comment: sorry , I didn't realize it. I asked the question in continuation to the above discussion, but if you say its not correct I will post a new question

Comment: It not that there is anything intrinsically wrong, it is just that your chances of an answer are almost nil :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is for MS Access and only refers to the database password, not user level security.

Answer (score 1):

Omit the user credentials, however make sure your application has permissions to access the network location (either the application account or the application users, depending on the security model used)